# How to get values from SharedPreferences from another Activity?

Tags: android

There is the main Activity with the following code in onCreate method:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
SharedPreferences prefs=MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("com.qerq.helloworldproject.PreferencesActivity", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
String editText=prefs.getString("edit_text", "default_edit_text_value");
boolean checkBox=prefs.getBoolean("check_box", true);
String list=prefs.getString("list", "default_list_value");

Log.i("edit_text_value", editText);
Log.i("check_box_value", String.valueOf(checkBox));
Log.i("list_value", list);
```

and there is xml layout for PreferencesActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:key="first_screen_key"
        android:summary="First summary"
        android:title="First title" >
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:persistent="true"
            android:title="Check Box Title"
            android:key="check_box_key"
            android:defaultValue="false"/>
        <ListPreference 
            android:persistent="true"
            android:title="List Title"
            android:key="list_key"
            android:entries="@array/entries"
            android:defaultValue="second_value"
            android:entryValues="@array/entries_values"/>
        <EditTextPreference 
            android:persistent="true"
            android:title="Edit Text Title"
            android:key="edit_text_key"
            android:defaultValue="Edit Text Value"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

But I get only default values always from code always! I need to change values using PreferencesActivity, but I also need to get values from source code in MainActivity. How can  I do it?

Comment: Have saved the preferences.. using SharedPreference Editor..?

Comment: I hoped to get default values from xml file.

Answer (score 3):

A `PreferenceActivity` will save the preferences into a *default* `SharedPreferences` which you do not need to access by name. Change the following line...

```
SharedPreferences prefs=MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("com.qerq.helloworldproject.PreferencesActivity", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

...to...

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```